# GMock - returning default value with ON_CALL for overloaded methods

Tags: c++, googlemock

I'm trying to write mock for a class which contains three overloaded methods, ie.:

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include <gmock/gmock.h>

using ::testing::_;
using ::testing::Return;
using ::testing::A;
using ::testing::ByRef;
using ::testing::Ref;
using ::testing::TypedEq;

struct Foo {
  int fooMethod(const int& intParam) { return 0; }
  int fooMethod(const float& floatParam) { return 0; }
  int fooMethod(const std::string& stringParam) { return 0; }
};

struct FooMock {
  FooMock() {
    ON_CALL(*this, fooMethod(_)).WillByDefault(Return(-1));
  }

  MOCK_METHOD1(fooMethod, int(const int& intParam));
  MOCK_METHOD1(fooMethod, int(const float& floatParam));
  MOCK_METHOD1(fooMethod, int(const std::string& stringParam));
};
```

but this gives an error:

```
 error: call of overloaded ‘gmock_fooMethod(const testing::internal::AnythingMatcher&)’ is ambiguous
```

I've also tried TypedEq() instead of "_", but it gives more obscure errors. I've checked GMock FAQ, Wiki and I didn't find solution - how can I return default value with ON_CALL for overloaded methods?

BR,
Lukasz

Answer (score 12, accepted):

@tx34 has the crux of the answer, but there are a few more issues in the code.

Firstly, the docs on [Selecting Between Overloaded Functions](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googlemock/docs/cook_book.md#selecting-between-overloaded-functions-selectoverload) are most appropriate.  You have three overloads of `fooMethod` with the same number of arguments but different argument types.  You're going to have to use a matcher that specifies the type.

Next, you need to define all your `Foo` functions which are to be mocked as `virtual`, or else invoking them through a `Foo` object won't call the derived mock functions.  Since you're defining `Foo` as a base class, it should also have a virtual destructor to avoid slicing.

Finally, you need to have `FooMock` inherit from `Foo`.

So putting it all together, you end up with something like:

```
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
#include "gmock/gmock.h"

using ::testing::_;
using ::testing::An;
using ::testing::Matcher;
using ::testing::TypedEq;
using ::testing::Return;

struct Foo {
  virtual ~Foo() {}
  virtual int fooMethod(const int&) { return 0; }
  virtual int fooMethod(const float&) { return 0; }
  virtual int fooMethod(const std::string&) { return 0; }
};

struct FooMock : Foo {
  FooMock() : Foo() {
    ON_CALL(*this, fooMethod(An<const int&>())).
        WillByDefault(Return(-1));
    ON_CALL(*this, fooMethod(Matcher<const float&>(_))).
        WillByDefault(Return(-2));
    ON_CALL(*this, fooMethod(TypedEq<const std::string&>("1"))).
        WillByDefault(Return(-3));
  }

  MOCK_METHOD1(fooMethod, int(const int& intParam));
  MOCK_METHOD1(fooMethod, int(const float& floatParam));
  MOCK_METHOD1(fooMethod, int(const std::string& stringParam));
};

TEST(Foo, foo) {
  std::shared_ptr<Foo> foo(new FooMock);
  auto foo_mock(std::dynamic_pointer_cast<FooMock>(foo));

  EXPECT_CALL(*foo_mock, fooMethod(Matcher<const int&>(_))).Times(1);
  EXPECT_CALL(*foo_mock, fooMethod(Matcher<const float&>(_))).Times(1);
  EXPECT_CALL(*foo_mock, fooMethod(Matcher<const std::string&>(_))).Times(1);

  EXPECT_EQ(-1, foo->fooMethod(1));
  EXPECT_EQ(-2, foo->fooMethod(1.0f));
  EXPECT_EQ(-3, foo->fooMethod("1"));
}


int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
  return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

Comment: Can you do the selection of overloaded functions that have different number of arguments? I do not see any guide on how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is TypedEq expects a value not a matcher. You can achieve what you want by:

```
ON_CALL(*this, fooMethod(An<ArgType>())).WillByDefault(Return(-1));
```

or

```
ON_CALL(*this, fooMethod(Matcher<ArgType>(_))).WillByDefault(Return(-1));
```

See also:

https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/docs/gmock_cook_book.md#selecting-between-overloaded-functions-selectoverload

https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/docs/gmock_cheat_sheet.md#wildcard

https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/docs/gmock_cheat_sheet.md#generic-comparison